# Error Constructing std::map<T, unique_ptr<S>> from an initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11

***C2280 - Attempting to reference a deleted function*** is the error I am getting when I attempt to construct an std::map> from an initializer_list

I've made the simplest possible code(below) representing my problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<string, unique_ptr<int>> MyMap{
        { "first" ,make_unique<int>(6)  },
        { "second",make_unique<int>(22) },
        { "third" ,make_unique<int>(86) }
    };
}
```

So I realize that unique_ptr cannot be copied, but since make_unique is returning an rvalue, shouldn't the unique_ptr being moved into the initializer_list?
By the way, if I replace unique_ptr with shared_ptr then the problem is solved, but is not the solution I am looking for, I would like to retain that initialization style and the unique_ptr.
So at which point this problematic call to a deleted function is happening exactly? There is a way to have it compile without replacing the unique_ptr?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't really work that way. You have to explicitly [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) the pointer.

Comment: I've enclosed the make_unique<int>() in the move function, still won't compile...have I done it wrong?  Can you show me an example of the proper way?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That's not the problem. The pointers are being properly moved into the initializer list. But they aren't being moved out of the initializer list and into the map. And I don't think there's any good way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, this is one of the limitations of `std::initializer_list` objects. They only offer `const` access to their elements, so it is not possible to move out of them. Your best bet is to initialize your map the old-fashioned way.

```
map<string, unique_ptr<int>> MyMap;
MyMap["first"] = make_unique<int>(6);
// etc.
```

If you need the map to be `const`, you can create a temporary map and move from that:

```
const map<string, unique_ptr<int>> myMap = [] {
    map<string, unique_ptr<int>> m;
    m["first"] = make_unique<int>(6);
    // etc.
    return m;  // RVO or implicit move
}();
```

You could also use the range constructor of `std::map`, but then you'd have to write a special iterator type for this yourself, which would be annoying.

Comment: Did you mean to add an invocation at the end of that lambda?

Comment: Well, this sucks... xD Then old fashion way it is :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, thanks for catching that. You could also have edited the answer yourself :)